# ruby on rails - Do Loop in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to display every files that belong to one given project (the relationship works fine, could check it using the Rails console).
Here is my 'Project' controller , I may need a do loop (to loop through each files , for 1 project) but I'm not sure :

```
def show
@project = Project.find(params[:id])
@pfile = Project.find(params[:id]).Pfiles.find(:all)

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @project }
  format.xml  { render :xml => @pfile }
end
end
```

This is my 'Project' view :

```
  <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <b>Name:</b>
  <%= @project.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Description:</b>
  <%= @project.description %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Files:</b>
  <%= @project.pfile.name %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_path(@project) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', projects_path %>
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If the relationship is set up correctly you can do this:

## controller

```
@pfiles = @project.pfiles
```

## view

```
<p>
  <b>Files:</b>
  <% @pfiles.each do |pfile| %>
    <%= pfile.name %>
  <% end %>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

easier yet... rely on the magic of rails.

in the controller

```
@project = Project.find(params[:id])
@pfiles = @project.pfiles
```

then in the view

```
<b>Files:</b>
<%= render @pfiles %>
```

then in views/pfiles/_pfile.html.erb

```
<%= pfile.name %>
```